# Especificaciones técnicas de uso para mi app android studio

Tags: android

He terminado una app con estas características:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 29
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.17'
```

Basándome en las anteriores características, quisiera saber cómo puedo explicar a mis usuarios que requisitos debe tener el dispositivo android para el correcto funcionamiento de mi app. Gracias

---

Saludos: Gracias por sus respuestas y si, el objetivo es explicar en una app store o a cualquier usuario que quiera usar mi app (en algunas app store esta información no aparece muy detallada). La idea es que las personas que quieran descargar mi app puedan saber exactamente que requisitos debe tener su dispositivo android para el correcto funcionamiento de mi app. Esto con el fin de evitar comentarios como que mi app no funciona, y en realidad esto se deba a que no cumplen con los requisitos para el uso de mi app. Disculpen la redundancia, pero creo que así se puede entender mi pregunta.

Aquí dejo una parte del AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Gracias de nuevo por sus respuestas y colaboración.

Comment: Explicar en dónde? En la tienda no te aparecen esos datos al momento de descargar?

Comment: Lo único restrictivo en esa configuración es: `minSdkVersion 15`, los dispositivos que tengan una versión de API inferior a la `15` no podrán usar esa aplicación. Todo lo relativo a eso está claramente explicado en la [documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning?hl=es#minsdkversion). Dicho eso, tu pregunta no es clara, lee la documentación y si aún te quedan dudas, plantéalas claramente para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Agrega tu AndroidManifest.xml también

Answer (score 0):

Las 2 propiedades importantes dentro del **build.gradle** en este caso son:

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 29
```

> [**minSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min) : indica desde que API tu aplicación es
> soportada.
>
> [**targetSdkVersion**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) indica con que API tu aplicación es compilada,
> Valor entero que designa el nivel de API al cual se dirige la
> aplicación. Si no se configura, el valor predeterminado es igual al
> valor asignado a la minSdkVersion.

De acuerdo a lo anterior puedes comentar a los usuarios que **el mínimo sistema operativo soportado por tu aplicación sería [Android 4.0.3 (API level 15](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms)** y se encuentra **compilada con Android 10 (API level 29)**, en este caso debes revisar los [cambios destacados al compilar con este sistema operativo Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/highlights).

En cuanto a tu `AndroidManifest.xml` no hay permisos definidos por lo tanto no hay información importante que comunicar al usuario.